# password protected .zip extracts to empty folder (without prompting for password)

Tags: command-line, zip

I've create a zip archive using the following command:

`zip -e myfolder.zip myfolder/`

Which prompts for a password and compresses the folder without errors. Now I'm trying to unzip the archive using this other command:

`unzip myfolder.zip`

which should supposedly ask for the password I set before, but doesn't - it just extracts an empty folder. I've tried using the `-p mypassword` option, but with the same results.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not use the `-r` option when creating the archive, your archive contains *only* the directory, and *not the files inside it*.

Apparently the encryption of a Zip file does not extend to protecting the directory structure, just the contents of the files. As a result, if a zip file contains only directories and no files, the encryption/decryption does nothing at all.

Comment: in other words I lost all my files for good?

Comment: Check the contents listing of your zip file: `unzip -l myfolder.zip`. If you have deleted the original folder, then it's lost because you never zipped its contents in the first place.

Comment: Today is the day that you learn to test your work.